# matplotlib does not draw major tick line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to draw pandas DataFrame with below style tick and grid lines:

[image]

But, with below code, I could not. Why?

```
def plog_test():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    for ax in axes:
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.HourLocator())
        hfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d %H:%M')
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)

    ts1.plot(ax=axes[0], y="count")
    ts1.plot(ax=axes[1], y="count")
    ts2.plot(ax=axes[0], y="count")
    ts2.plot(ax=axes[1], y="count")

plog_test()
```

The result is as below:

[image]

`ts` is time series as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to reputation restrictions...

Does it yield any kind of error?
Also how exactly are you implementing your function?

You need to be more clear when it comes to asking these questions, the more information about why you think it isn't working the easier it would be for someone else to identify the solution.

Also check this out, I bet what you are looking for is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html) in the pandas visualization documentation